# add a value in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

As you can see there is a value already on the (total)textbox which i filtered on a table...and if i type a number on the (score)textboxes it will automatically add on the current value of the total(textbox)...can anyone help me whats wrong to my code because its not working as i expected..it wont calculate.

html code:

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(empty($name[0])){$name[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA" value="" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB" value="" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 3: <br />
<input type="text" name="optC" value="" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 4: <br />
<input type="text" name="optD" value="" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onchange="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="totals" value="<?php if(empty($total[0])){$total[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[0];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
</form>
```

script code to calculate:

```
<script>
function optTotal() {
        var a1 = document.forms[0].optA;
        var b1 = document.forms[0].optB;
        var c1 = document.forms[0].optC;
        var d1 = document.forms[0].optD;
        var xtotal = document.forms[0].totals;
        if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
            a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
        else
            a1 = 0;

        if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
            b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
        else
            b1 = 0;

        if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
            c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
        else
            c1 = 0;

        if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
            d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
        else
            d1 = 0;
        if (xtotal.value && xtotal.value != "")
            xtotal = parseFloat(xtotal.value);
        else
            xtotal = 0;

        var total = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + xtotal;
        document.forms[0].total.value = total;
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
set id for total input e.g TOTAL
document.getElementById('TOTAL').setAttribute('value',total)
```

or change this line `total` to `totals`

```
document.forms[0].totals.value = total
```

Comment: how come when i type on the fist score textbox it add perfectly but if i change the number it multiply on the total?

Comment: it is a javascript function that dont allow letters and special characters to be inputed on the textboxes.

Comment: example value 8 on (total)textbox if i type 2 on optA it will become 10 and i type 2 again on optB the result will become 14 and if i type 2 again in optC it will become 20 in total.

Comment: your error for isNumberic check it with jquery remove from on keyUp and work correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in script JS:

Is not:

```
document.forms[0].total.value = total;
```

But:

```
document.forms[0].totals.value = total;
```

Answer (score -1):

1 Make sure your "isnumeric" function runs correctly and is accessible, so it doesn't abort the script.

2 Your "totals" name is incorrect here:

```
document.forms[0].total.value = total;
```

change it to:

```
document.forms[0].totals.value = total;
```

3 Use your browser console to see errors!

Comment: why is it its not doing addition perfectly??when i type its like  doubling what number that i type and add to total value.

Comment: it is because you are adding it to the xtotals value each time (which already is the total).. just remove it from the last calculation!

Comment: how because if i remove it it wont calculate the way it so pose to do in the first place?

Comment: Remove: "var xtotal = document.forms[0].totals;" and change your calculation line to: "var total = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1;"